# Is it possible to figure out if message received was forwarded even if the sender chose the "hide sender's name" option?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I created a telegram bot using python-telegram-bot library,
at one point I ask the user of the bot to send his location, and I want to make sure that the location he sent is truly his location and not forwarded from other person.

telegram offers the sender an option to "hide sender's name", is there anyway I can figure out that this message was forwarded and that the GPS location wasn't forwarded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Message`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) has the `forward_date` field for all forwarded messages indpendent of whether the original sender is accessible or not. This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I have tried forwarding 2 messages to the bot and check the update.message.forward_date:

1. Forwarded message without choosing"hide sender's name": it actually returns the date of the original message.
2. Forwarded message with choosing "hide sender's name" option: it returns None.

I am looking for a way to overcome the second case and figure out that the msg was forwarded, even if the user hides the sender's name.